# What do you call additions after fermentation?

Tags: recipe, additives

Adding hops after fermentation is referred to as dry hopping (duh).  But folks also add things like cucumber and hibiscus to the beer after fermentation. What's the proper way to refer to these additions?

Comment: Add bacon to a beer is called Dry Porking. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward....they're called "post fermentation additions".

Comment: Googled that phrase, seems legit.  [UC Davis paper using the term in reference to wine making](http://wineserver.ucdavis.edu/pdf/attachment/89%20tannin%20addition%20and%20sensory.pdf) , so does [this](http://servicebrewing.com/juice-day-at-the-brewery-just-one-of-the-post-fermentation-additions/) blog post

Comment: You doubted me?  :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is a bit of a gray area as far as official terminology. I have experienced several people over-emphasizing finger quotes and suggesting they would "Dry hop" with... cucumber or whatever. I personally dont do too many additions like this but would describe it as "secondary with..." regardless of it being in a primary or secondary vessel.

I'm guessing this does not actually answer your question but instead reaffirms that there is no proper word and it needs an official designation, my suggestion is dry pitching... that seems legit!

Comment: Or wet pitching for fresh ingredients. I dont see either of these taking off but I would be curious what other suggestions people could come up with. It would be exciting if you were the one to start the conversation and this community could change the world!... of homebrewing!... specifically adding stuff post fermentation...